# Remove Leading Zeroes from struct in Python

Tags: python

I am using Python for serial communication over a Beagle Bone. I need to transmit data in hex format. So I used `struct` like this:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import serial
import struct

UART.setup("UART1")

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyO1', baudrate = 19200)
print ser.portstr
ser.open()

tx_hex = 0x1234
tx_str = struct.pack('!I', tx_hex)

if ser.isOpen():
    print "Serial is open!"
    ser.write(tx_str)
else:
    print "Serial is closed!"
ser.close()
```

However, I receive `00 00 12 34` (in hex) whereas I would want it to be just `12 34`. How do I get rid of the leading zeroes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different format for the `struct`:

```
tx_str = struct.pack('!H', tx_hex)
```

See also https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters

Comment: I came back just to update that I had found this solution, but by then you had already provided the right answer. Thanks Brian!